# Error While Installing Fabric Chaincode: _lifecycle.syscc: no such file or directory

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

While trying to **install chaincode** using `Fabric v2.1`, I am encountering an error. Does anyone face similar issues? My peer is running fine and able to join the channel as well. I am able to list the channel details as well.

**Note:** I am doing Native installation without using docker images for running orderer and peer.

Highly appreciate for your support and looking forward to hear from you.

**Error:**

> chaincode install failed with status: 500 - error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 44688cc50afeda03e3f5e7735ae650030952477b6bdfce83064582f42bec6c84: could not launch chaincode _lifecycle.syscc: error building chaincode: error building image: failed to get chaincode package for external build: could not get legacy chaincode package '_lifecycle.syscc': open /home/vagrant/ledger/ORG2/peer1-org2/ledger/chaincodes/_lifecycle.syscc: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after upgrading from 1.4. In my case the problem was in the old config file for the peer.

Make sure you have next lines in your core.yaml:

```
chaincode:
    ...
    # enabled system chaincodes
    system:
        _lifecycle: enable
```